# I am having difficulties reinstalling 12.10 and need help

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, mount

My reinstall of Ubuntu 12.10 seems to be taking forever. I see occasional notes that come up in the small window reporting events, but they mean nothing to me.

I was tempted to hit the having trouble link during the reinstall and am still in that mode. I told it to save installed programs and I presently have about 146 programs installed.

The troubles began when Ubuntu would not boot well with a message "mount failed," referring to about 6-different failures following the "mount:" message, and then ending with "instmfts," or something to that effect. I went to the "help" menu, I typed in "mount" which for a time seemed to mount manually, followed by "reboot" which for a time worked pretty well.

However, over time, this procedure did not work at all, and I would have to use a repair disk just to boot. Once I shut down, it would occasionally reboot, but more and more I needed to use the boot repair each time, which did not seem to repair anything permanently.

Please help. I have also tried and apparently succeeded at reinstalling GRUB. I am not  well skilled at programming but have enough knowledge to get into the terminal and to change and list files in various directories, but that is about all.

Otherwise, I am loving Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your hard disk is failing or maybe you are having problems with RAM.

Can you run a liveDVD or liveUSB without problems? If that's the case then that would suggest problems with the hard disk.

If not, maybe it is the RAM or some other piece of hardware.